# check unused variable in C project

Tags: c, linux, debugging, compiler-construction

I developed new C project and I use some time variables to debug or to check value ...

I want to be sure if I don't forget any unused variable after achieving project.

there is a Linux utilities or command to do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some compilers can issue a warning for you when an automatic variable is unused. Try

```
gcc -Wunused-variable
clang -Wunused-variable
```

Comment: `-Wall` should turn it on by default.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev It says in the `gcc` documentation that not all may be with `-Wall`. `-Wextra -Wunused` will give you most unused warnings with `gcc`

Comment: when it comes down to checking variables, I also consider adding `-Wshadow` as a flag to my compiler .

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html says *-Wunused-variable Warn whenever a local variable or non-constant static variable is unused aside from its declaration. This warning is enabled by -Wall.*

Answer (score 0):

I would do such things with preprocessor statements.

For example, you could define:
    #define DEBUG

and in code

```
#ifdef DEBUG

//debug code in here

#endif
```

When compiling the final code, just don't define DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

use macros in your debug instead of using variable directelly. this is more proper

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use cppcheck, it comes in ubuntu repositories or you can download and compile the code from:

[cppcheck](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/&ei=Sp6gUoT_LMTV2QXT9IHoDw&usg=AFQjCNEOXuSSGTC0DdET3GXQZto4jUi08g&sig2=ZIwX14ldVKDOMmKjqVE6xA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.b2I)

It's an awesome tool of static code analysis that will tell you some of the code errors you can make.